# X-UA-Compatible meta tag in ASP.NET 4.0 site doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-applications

I am writting an asp.net 4 application and i want my application to work in compatiable mode (IE8 AND IE9) .

I have used following meta tag so far and it is not working.
  (HAVE TRIED WITH "IE=8" AS WELL)

I have followed this thread but no luck so far;

[Setting X-UA-Compatible meta tag in ASP.NET 4.0 site doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368220/setting-x-ua-compatible-meta-tag-in-asp-net-4-0-site-doesnt-work)

I don't know if it is a known bug?
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/581278/setting-x-ua-compatible-meta-tag-in-asp-net-4-0-site-doesn-t-work-yes-it-s-at-the-top#

ADDED:

If i remove 'StyleSheetTheme' from the page tag then it renders in compatiable mode.

- 

Any way to fix it?

**Possible solution:**

It works if i add meta tag dynamically on the page load event and leven the stylesheet value in the page tag.

> Dim metaTag As New HtmlMeta()
>
> metaTag.Attributes.Add("http-equiv", "X-UA-Compatible")
>
> metaTag.Attributes.Add("content", "ID=EmulateIE7")
>
> Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, metaTag)

**Do you think its a right way of doing it? any other better solution?**

Answer (score 0):

try adding the header to your iis settings or in your web.config file: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deviations/archive/2009/05/07/how-to-enable-ie-8-compatibility-view-for-your-whole-web-site-or-for-specific-web-site-directories.aspx